# UnsatisfiedDependencyException after changing Entity annotated classes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am writing a web app using Spring and Hibernate.
I get this exception:

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'trustDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.cybertrust.tms.config.DemoAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
>   ....

The configuration I'm using was working fine, until I refactored the classes in the Entities package i.e. the @Entity annotated classes that are mapped in a mysql database. I didn't change anything in my configuration or DAO where the exception occurs. So I really can't trace the problem.

**My configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.cybertrust.tms")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-mysql.properties" })
@PropertySource({ "classpath:model.properties" })
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

@Bean
public DataSource myDataSource() {

    // create connection pool
    ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    // set the jdbc driver
    try {
        myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");        
    }
    catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }

    // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
    logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));

    // set database connection props
    myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

    // set connection pool props
    myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
    myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
    myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));     
    myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

    return myDataSource;
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

    // set hibernate properties
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

    return props;               
}


// need a helper method 
// read environment property and convert to int

private int getIntProperty(String propName) {

    String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

    // now convert to int
    int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

    return intPropVal;
}   

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

    // create session factories
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    // set the properties
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

    // setup transaction manager based on session factory
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    return txManager;
}

@Bean
TrustModel model() {

    return new TrustModel();

}

/*@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
Trust trust() {
    return new Trust();
}*/
}
```

**DAO implementation class:**

```
@Repository
public class TrustDAOImpl implements TrustDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public TrustAssessments getDeviceTrust(int id) {

    //Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    //TrustAssessments trust = currentSession.get(TrustAssessments.class, id);


    return null;
}
}
```

In the DAO the commented out lines are just to make sure that the Entity TrustAssessments doesn't create some kind of problem.

**EDIT**

As @trim24 pointed out in his comment, I checked the end of the stack trace. However I was still not able to pinpoint the problem. The exception at the end of the stack trace is this:

> Nov 24, 2019 10:23:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
>   SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/tms-rest] threw load() exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:814)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:256)
>       ....

I also tried deleting all the Entity classes and kept only configuration, service and DAO, and I get the same exceptions. So the refactoring of the Entity classes really didn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: SessionFactory probably has some autowired class, that spring is unable to find. You need to look at the end of stack trace to check which dependency spring is unable to find.